# C# 32Feet.Net can't detect Bluetooth device

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I used 32Feet.Net try to detect a Bluetooth device, but it's not working.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uddb9.jpg

Then I used Windows system Bluetooth function, it can detect that device.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Clr1.jpg

And here is my code, is there something wrong with my code or...?
Please help me to solve this problem, many thanks!

```
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BluetoothSearchTool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool RUN = false;

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!RUN)
            {
                RUN = true;
                Thread t = new Thread(Search);
                t.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                RUN = false;
            }
        }

        private void Search()
        {
            BluetoothClient bc = new BluetoothClient();
            BluetoothDeviceInfo[] bdi_list = null;

            ButtonText("Stop");
            AppendText("Start Searching" + "\r\n");

            while (RUN)
            {
                bdi_list = bc.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
                if (bdi_list.Length != 0)
                {
                    foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo bdi in bdi_list)
                    {
                        AppendText(bdi.DeviceName + "\r\n");
                        AppendText(bdi.DeviceAddress + "\r\n");
                        AppendText("-----------------" + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
            }

            ButtonText("Search");
            AppendText("Stop Searching" + "\r\n");
        }

        private void ButtonText(string text)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ButtonText(text); }));
                return;
            }
            btnSearch.Text = text;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        private void AppendText(string content)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { AppendText(content); }));
                return;
            }
            rtbContent.AppendText(content);
            rtbContent.ScrollToCaret();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code looks ok, but I think you need to inform yourself about the differences between Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth LE.

Comment: @Risto Do you mean, maybe I should try to detect BLE devices?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for Risto's hint! that is a BLE device,
and my answer as below,

Development environment: VS 2017

Windows application: .NET Framework 4.6.1

Step 1.
Before we install some package,
we need to set up Package management format,

> In Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> General -> Package Management to use PackageReference

Step 2.
Install InTheHand.BluetoothLE & UwpDesktop via NuGet package manager console

> PM> Install-Package InTheHand.BluetoothLE -Version 4.0.22
>
> PM> Install-Package UwpDesktop -Version 10.0.14393.3

Step 3.
Coding

```
using InTheHand.Bluetooth;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BluetoothSearchTool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool RUN = false;
        static string MSG = "";

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!RUN)
            {
                RUN = true;
                Thread t = new Thread(Search);
                t.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                RUN = false;
            }
        }

        private void Search()
        {
            ButtonText("Stop");
            AppendText("Start Searching" + "\r\n");

            while (RUN)
            {
                var discoveryTask = TestDeviceDiscovery();
                discoveryTask.Wait();
                AppendText(MSG);
            }

            ButtonText("Search");
            AppendText("Stop Searching" + "\r\n");
        }

        private void ButtonText(string text)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ButtonText(text); }));
                return;
            }
            btnSearch.Text = text;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        private void AppendText(string content)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { AppendText(content); }));
                return;
            }
            rtbContent.AppendText(content);
            rtbContent.ScrollToCaret();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        private static async Task<bool> TestDeviceDiscovery()
        {
            var discoveredDevices = await Bluetooth.ScanForDevicesAsync();
            MSG = "";
            foreach (BluetoothDevice bd in discoveredDevices)
            {
                MSG += bd.Name + "\r\n" + bd.Id + "\r\n" + "-----------------" + "\r\n";
            }
            return discoveredDevices?.Count > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Done!!! here's the result!!!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcWNH.jpg

Hope this case can help those in need.